# Add properties to ng-repeat on page load from get request

Tags: angularjs, arrays, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have been trying to push properties that are not in an `ng-repeat` that are bound to select lists.

I have a form that has many selects and there is an option for the user to select `other` and enter a value which then gets added to the select list as the option. When the user submits the form everything is ok. The user can edit the form and I am trying to push the value if it is not in the `ng-repeat`.

I have many `ng-repeats` and thought I could possibly make an array of the names of my `ng-repeats` and match the object property with the name, if true, `for in` on the object and see if didn't exist, if true push it into the array of the `ng-repeat`, after trying this I get the `duplicate ng-repeats error from angular`. I'm not sure if this is the way to do it or is there an easy angular way, because when I inspect the `select` I can see angular is trying to set that model property in my `ng-repeat` but is displayed like `<option value="? string:r2O ?"></option>`

Is there a way to tell angular that this is the option without try to loop through every `ng-repeat` and then adding it to the array?

This is what I have been trying: (there are more)

```
minor.circuitNoA = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', 'Other'];
minor.circuitDesignationA = ['Socket ring circuit', 'Socket radial', 'Lights', 'Lights up', 'Lights down', 'Exterior lights', 'Lighting - fire alarm', 'Fire alarm', 'Security panel', 'Cooker', 'Cooker - hob', 'Oven', 'Immersion heater', 'Shower pump', 'Electric pump', 'Central heating', 'Storage heating', 'Underfloor heating', 'Sub main to', 'Supply to', 'PV supply', 'Blank', 'Spare', 'Unknown', 'Other'];
minor.refMethodA = ['A', 'B', 'C', '100', '101', '102', '103', 'Other'];
minor.liveMmA = ['1', '1.5', '2.5', '4', '6', '10', '16', '25', '35', '50', '70', '95', 'Other'];
minor.cpcMmA = ['1', '1.5', '2.5', '4', '6', '10', '16', '25', '35', '50', '70', '95', 'SWA', 'Other'];
```

Array of names to match `ng-repeats`

```
    var selectCheck = ['circuitNoA', 'circuitDesignationA', 'refMethodA', 'liveMmA', 'disConTimeA', 'bsEnA', 'typeNoA', 'ratingA', 'breakingCapacityA', 'rcdOpTimeA', 'r1A', 'rnA', 'r2A', 'r1R12A', 'r1R2R2A', 'liveLiveA', 'liveEarthA'];
```

The main event :

```
for (var i = 0; i < selectCheck.length; i++) {
  console.log('selectA: ', minor[selectCheck[i]]);
  console.log('selectName: ', selectCheck[i]);
  var selectName = selectCheck[i];
  for (var t in minorObj) { // comes from the get (full object)
    console.log(t + 'A');
    if (selectName == t + 'A') {
      var valToCheck = minor.minorWorks.test[t];
      var arrToCheck = minor[selectCheck[i]];
      console.log('match');
      console.log('obj to check', t);
      console.log('value to check:', minor.minorWorks.test[t]);
      console.log('array to check: ', minor[selectCheck[i]]);
      for (var m = 0; m < arrToCheck.length; m++) {
        // console.log('logging m:', arrToCheck[m]);
        if(arrToCheck[m] == valToCheck){
          console.log('here');
          console.log('valtoCheck in for array', valToCheck);
          console.log('arrToCheck in for array', arrToCheck[m]);

        }else{
          // arrToCheck.push(valToCheck)
        }
      }
      break;
    }
  }
}
```